# How to get heightPercent?

Tags: android, android-percentrelativelayout

I'm trying to get `heightPercent` property value to achieve that I tried the bellow code but doesn't work  :

## Code

```
    PercentRelativeLayout mPercentRelativeLayout = new PercentRelativeLayout(getActivity());
    mPercentRelativeLayout = (PercentRelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.percentRelativeLayout);

    PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mPercentRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams());
    Log.v("PercentRL Height :", "" + layoutParams.getPercentLayoutInfo().heightPercent);
```

## output

```
PercentRL Height :﹕ -1
```

I would appreciate any help.